# TFS 2018 MSBUILD Download files task equivalent?

Tags: tfs, build, msbuild

We are moving to TFS 2018 from 2012 and I'm working on migrating the builds.  One of the builds has a few mtbwa:DownloadFiles activities in it but I don't see an equivalent way to do this in the new build system.  We have a few utilities in a different branch that are used to build installers.  So I need to download those utils before completing the build.  How would I do this in the new build system?

Comment: Looks like the only way to do this is to use the TF.exe and issue the get command...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the files are in source control, then you can map the source directly in **Get source** step.

Then the files will be automatically downloaded to the  `$(build.sourcesDirectory)` by deafult on the agent machine.

After that you can also add a **[Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/build-release/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=vsts)** task to copy the files to any location as needed.

If the files are not in source control, you can also use the **Copy Files** task to copy them, but you need to make sure that the service account has the proper permission to access the source folder.

---

**UPDATE:**

If the team projects are in same collection, map sources in `Get Sources` step is also available. **You need to manually specify the `Server path`** (Click **...** can only navigate to the root path of current team project).

e.g.:

In below screenshot I entered the server path `$/2017ScrumProjectFromVS/WpfTest`

This also works with the **Copy Task**, that means you can copy the files directly from another team project which in the same collection.

[image]

Comment: The files are in source control, however, they are in a different repository/team project.  So unfortunately this won't work for me.  I'm looking into the rest api to try to download them that way but I'm having some trouble getting the path right.

Comment: @Sam Are the team projects in the same collection? If yes, then you can specify the server path directly when map the sources. See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, they are in the same collection.  I didn't think that would work since I had to select the repository above... I assume it was bound to that.  Thanks, I'll give this a shot.  I had created a Powershell script to perform this though.

Comment: @Sam So, the issue was resolved, right? Then you could Accept it as answer, This can be beneficial to other community members reading this thread.